# Integrating by Parts $\int\limits^{2}_{0}pydy$ - A calculation related to flowrate.

Tags: integration, fluid-dynamics

Happy new year everyone!

I have a question that I struggle related to integration by parts.

Suppose I'm going to solve the following using integration by parts.
$$\int\limits^{2}_{0}pydy$$
Where $p$ is a function of $y$.

I know the formula for integration by parts for definite integrals:
$$\int\limits_{a}^{b}udv=uv\Big|_{a}^{b} - \int\limits_{a}^{b}vdu$$

Thus I'm considering:
$$u=y \text{ and } dv=pdy$$

This gives me:
$$du=dy \text{ and } v=\int pdy$$

Now by substituting into the original formula,
I have:
$$\begin{align}
\int\limits^{2}_{0}pydy &= \left(y\int pdy\right)\Big|_{0}^{2} - \int\limits_{0}^{2}(\int pdy)dy
\end{align}$$

I also have the function $Q(y)$ where,
$$Q(y) = \int\limits_{0}^{y}p(t)dt$$

Now this is the place I find it confusing to substitute the limits of the integral.

And my goal is to write the integration by parts equation in terms of this function $Q(y)$ because $Q(y)$ is actually a two-dimensional flow rate where we have $Q(0)=0$, $Q(2)=k$ a known value.

Appreciate your help

Comment: Just replace $$\int p(y) dy \to \int_{0}^{y} p(t) dt = Q(y)$$ as they are the same expression.

Comment: @MatthewCassell I thought that too. But I'm still confused as to why should them be the same expression. One is a definite integral and the other one is not...

Comment: The indefinite integral represents all antiderivatives of $p$. $Q$ is one of those antiderivatives. In other words, $Q$ is the indefinite integral but with a specific choice for $C$.

Comment: @Andrew Thank you! It makes sense!